# True or false: $a<b$ also has the meaning of $b \geq a$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a true or false question :
$a<b$ also has the meaning of $b \geq a$.
in my book it is written "false". can someone explain why?

Comment: What if $a=b$? Are both statements true? Are they both false? Or do they differ?

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2 < 2$ is false.

$2\ge2$ is true.

This one counterexample - and one is all it takes - shows that $a<b$ and $b\ge a$ do not have the same meaning.

Comment: excellent! thank you!